# iOS: indexPath.row, UICollectionView, and Images

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to display through a `UICollectionView` only 9 pictures in my main iphone screen. But I have a problem with the displaying. My first picture is always repeated 2 times (in position 1 and position 2 of the row 1).

Something wrong in my code ?

```
// Define the number of Cell.
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

return  9; }


// The cell that is returned must be retrieved from a call to -dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    static NSString *IdCell = @"Cell";

     SSCollectionViewCell *cell = (SSCollectionViewCell *) [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier: IdCell forIndexPath: indexPath];
    int imageNumber = indexPath.row % 9;

    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"M2_img_%d@2x.png", imageNumber]];

    return cell;

    }
```

Comment: code looks fine...check your images M2_img_0@2x.png & M2_img_1@2x.png

Comment: [comment removed for inaccuracy]

Comment: My pictures are ok and named correctly ... :(

Comment: Solution: Clean and clear all the project.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you need to specify how many sections you have in the UICollectionView? You already have the delegate method numberOfItemsInSection, right? Now, in the numberOfSectionsInCollectionView delegate method, did you specify 1? as in:

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView: (UICollectionView *)collectionView {
  return 1; //if its just 9 images
  }